# Why did the Starks treat Bran as a brother?

Tags: game-of-thrones

When Bran arrived back to Winterfell, obviously every time he met another member of his family they hugged him and were very happy to see him.
He never kept it a secret that

> he was actually not Bran, and that Bran is dead.

Yet, everyone kept treating him as a Stark family member.
He was there in every meeting and council and also in a closed family-member-only conversation, even though he was actually a stranger.

Why would they let the Three-Eyed Raven keep Bran's status as a part of a big house family, including him in meetings of the highest ranks, and of course, keep showing affection as you would to a brother?

Comment: I think you’ve picked up an incorrect idea somewhere. Bran never died, and so that was the Bran that they know.

Comment: Bran didn't die. It was two unfortunate bystanders who were burned and presented as Bran and Rickon because the real Stark boys successfully escaped.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because Bran is the Three-Eyed Raven and the Three-Eyed Raven is Bran. Neither technically died as Bran became the Three-Eyed Raven when the previous one died and Bran himself never died. When he’s saying he’s not Bran anymore he’s just referring to him becoming the Three-Eyes Raven not that he himself has died.

And of course just because a family member starts acting weird doesn’t mean they’re not your family anymore. He is still Bran and still their brother, just a weird version of himself.